# Can I run multiple Spark History Servers in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, high-availability

We use Spark History Server to analyze our Spark runs, and we have a lot of them. This causes a high load on the server, since logs are analyzed lazily (i.e. on the first request).

I was wondering if we can scale out this service, or just scale it up? Is it version-dependant?

Since it's a concurrency issue, I rather get a trustworthy answer instead of running it and hoping for the best.

Thanks!